# You do not have permission to do this operation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am a site collection administrator. When I go into SharePoint Designer 2010 I can see everything. However, when I edit a Master Page, or Page Layout, I get the following error:

> > You do not have permission to do this operation. Ask your site administrator to change your permissions and then try again, or log on with a user account that has this permission. To log on with a different user account click OK.

I have made sure that all the files on the site are checked-in/approved, and still no luck.

All Designer options are enabled in Central Admin.

Anyone have any ideas for things to look at, or try?

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the answers given in this thread [you do not have permission to do this operation + SP Designer 2010 Error](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/a94d6991-4f56-42b1-90ba-9bee7c10f578)